# loop through datatable and run stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to loop through a datatable, that will pass information to my stored procedure but it isn't working.

even though it works when i manuelly

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim dv As New DataView
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dv = SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)

            dt = dv.ToTable()


            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

                If row("vtr_gen10").ToString() = "y" Or row("vn10").ToString() = "a" Or row("vtr_gen10").ToString() = "p" Then
                    Dim SQLCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
                    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
                    SQLCon.ConnectionString = SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString

                    SQLCon.Open()
                    sqlcmd.CommandText = "protest" ' Stored Procedure to Call
                    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 'Setup Command Type
                    sqlcmd.Connection = SQLCon 'Active Connection

                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row("id"))
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "Y")


                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    SQLCon.Close()

                End If

            Next

        End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working?"  Have you stepped through your code to see if the code inside of your `For Each` is running or if your `If` block code is running?

Comment: when i instert a break point i dont see anything happen and nothing is added to my destination table which makes me feel the stored procedure isnt running

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on your very first statement in your Sub, does the breakpoint get hit?  If not, then the problem may be that you're not setting up your event handler correctly.  If it does, then you should be able to step through the code and see what your Select statment returns.

Comment: the executenonquery gets hit but its passing parameters to a stored procedure that inserts data into another table and nothing shows up. also i am looping through 100 rows and i dont think it ever loops

Comment: ahh alright i realized what is happening it is looping through the first two rows and then stops

Comment: the reason is it worked the first time, but my stored procedure doesnt allow duplicates so i think what is happening is its looping to fast for the procedure

Comment: is there anyway to solve this

Comment: @bugz: what you described makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.  Whether it runs in 5ms or 100 seconds is immaterial if the data in your datatable contains duplicates and the proc doesn't allow them.  What exactly do you mean by "it stops".  What stops?  Does it error out or simply time out?  Have you run sql profiler to ensure the procedure is being called?

Comment: well it loops through the first 2 records and adds them and then it stops looping

Comment: i think it may simply timeout but it doesnt make sense because i close and reopen the connection on each loop

Comment: @bugz: The timeout has nothing to do with opening/closing the connection since the Connection-Pool handles the State behind the scenes for every connection with same ConnectionString. If your Table doesn't allow duplicates, you should ensure that no duplicates are inserted, whether with Identity-Increment or logically in your SP. But without knowing what the SP does, we couldn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure the IF criteria is being met after the first two records? One thing to look for is spaces or other string anomalies such as carraige returns in your database...

Row("vn10").ToString for example may for some reason be "a " instead of "a". Might be worth putting in a temporary debug line such as :

```
Throw New Exception("[" & Row("vn10").ToString & "]")
```

or inspect length on some records that erroneously fail.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing seems to be wrong with your code, but if you think its because its moving too fast, try adding sleep using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds)`